# A short program that takes input lower case letters it gives the upper case letters and exits at when the enter key is pressed

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, scanf, enter

The conversion works correctly but when I press enter, when asked for a lower case, it executes an enter (\n) and doesn't exit or stop.

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



main()
{
 char ch;
 printf("Press a letter: ");
 while (scanf(" %c",&ch)!='\n')
    {
        printf("%c\n",ch-32);     
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program is incorrect:

- `scanf` does *not* return the character that has been read, it returns the number of scanned items
- One way to deal with `'\n'` is to check `if (ch == '\n') break;`
- You need to check if a character is indeed a letter before subtracting 32
- You should use a `toupper` function instead of using subtraction directly.

Comment: We assume the user will write a lower case letter. Well my professor told us that we can only use break function if he allows, and in the exercise there's no mention of break. Other condition is that we should perform this without using outside functions, for example, my professor didn't teach us toupper. We are still in the begining of c (2 weeks of classes)

Comment: @user3397159 You could then use `scanf("%c",&ch)==1 && ch != '\n'` condition for your `while` loop.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&ch)` will never set ch to `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>        

    main()
    {
     char ch;
     printf("Press a letter: ");
     while (1)
        {
           scanf(" %c",&ch);
           if(ch=='\n')
               break;
           printf("%c\n",ch-32);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&ch)` will never set ch to `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf(" %c",&ch)` will never set `ch` to `\n` as the space in the format consumes all white-space, including `'\n'` before moving on to `"%c"`.

Further, the return value from `scanf()` is EOF or the number of successfully parsed arguments, not`ch`.  (not `"%n"` though)

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// No need for #include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  int ch;  // use int
  printf("Press a letter: ");
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && (ch != '\n')) {
    printf("%c\n", toupper(ch));     
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

OP states in another comment "we should perform this without using outside functions, for example, my professor didn't teach us toupper".  Let's assume `stdio` functions are OK and `ctype` ones are not.

```
  // Assume ASCII encoding

  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && (ch != '\n')) {
    if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
      ch += 'A' - 'a';
    }
    printf("%c\n", ch);     
  }

  // Not assuming ASCII encoding, but letters a-z, A-Z

  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && (ch != '\n')) {
    static const char *az = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static const char *AZ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;
    for (i=0; az[i]; i++) {
      if (ch == az[i]) {
        ch = AZ[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    printf("%c\n", ch);     
  }
```